# Explaining print test_list

Tags: python, python-2.7

could you explain to me in detail the second half of program?  I understand **input_list[0] = 10** is a variable where it has a **range of 1 - 10**, but where did the list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`, `[10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, and `[10, 5, 5]` come from?

```
def list_changer(input_list):
    input_list[0] = 10

    input_list = range(1, 10)
    print(input_list)
    input_list[0] = 10
    print(input_list)

>>> test_list = [5, 5, 5]
>>> list_changer(test_list)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> print test_list
[10, 5, 5]
```

Thank you in advance for all of your help.

Comment: Read about the `range()` function.  It creates and returns such lists.

Comment: One more thing you need to know is that lists are passed per reference (i. e. changes done to one are done to the original and thus have effect also after the function finished).  This is why you change the `[5, 5, 5]` to a `[10, 5, 5]`.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, the second list of numbers [10, 2, 3....] is being called which is why you start at 10, stop at 5, step are at 5. Is that the proper way of thinking?

Comment: See [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: @dawg huh? That has very little to do with the OPs code. There is no keyword argument in sight, mutable or not.

Comment: Is this really a three-upvotes-from-20-views question?

Comment: Any and every bit of info helps. I understand there's no argument stated but now I know about default parameter values.  Thank you for the article, @dawg

Comment: @Eddy: The effect demonstrated by your code comes from the fact that Python functions get passed a reference to an object, not a value. There's an excellent talk by Brandon Rhodes where he explains this concept in detail: [PyOhio 2011: Names, Objects, and Plummeting From The Cliff](http://pyvideo.org/video/542/pyohio-2011-names-objects-and-plummeting-from) It's a bit lengthy, but it's worth getting this fundamental concept right early on.

Comment: Thanks, @LukasGraf. I'm watching it right now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `id`

```
def list_changer(input_list):
    input_list[0] = 10
    print id(input_list)
    input_list = range(1, 10)
    print(input_list)
    input_list[0] = 10
    print(input_list)


>>>test_list = [5, 5, 5]
>>>print id(test_list)
>>>list_changer(test_list)
>>>print test_list

#output

139794448752512
139794448752512
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[10, 5, 5]
```

From this we can see that `id` of `test_list` is same as `input_list` in the `1st` line of function.That is both are referencing to `[5,5,5]`.So changes to `test_list` or `input_list`(1st line) will affect to all variables referencing it.`1st` line is where changes occuring for `[5,5,5]`.

Then `input_list = range(1, 10)`.This time `input_list` is referencing `range(1, 10)`.Still `[10,5,5]` is referencing by variable `test_list`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, this really does give me more of an insight as to where the codes are running off of.

Answer (score 1):

You should notice that are two different variables named `input_list`:

1. The first is declared **globally** as `test_list`, initialized by `[5,5,5]` and passed as an argument with the name `input_list` to the function `list_changer`.
2. The second is declared **locally** within the function `list_changer`, initialized by `range(1,10)` and overrode the name of the first one.

You can check this by printing `id(input_list)` each time you print the value.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't correct. There is no global `input_list`. The variable in the global scope is named `test_list`, not `input_list`.

Comment: @LukasGraf test_list is the same as the input_list passed by argument. I didnt notice that is named differently outside,but they are the same variabe.

Comment: They end up referencing the same list, but they're not the same name. So it's not at all a scoping issue.